# WhatsApp Business On-Premises API Couldn't find `error_subcodes` documentations

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

I am using "WhatsApp Business On-Premises API" for submitting templates. When something is wrong with template i.e. formatting whatsapp throws exception in this format

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 100,
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "fbtrace_id": <id>,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_subcode": 2388047,
    "error_user_msg": "Message body can't have more than two consecutive newline characters.",
    "error_user_title": "Message body format is Incorrect"
  }
}
```

i want documentation for all the `error_subcodes` so that i can translate them and show bases on the language for the user who is submitting the template.
PS: i have seen https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/errors#error but doesn't give all the `error_subcodes` fall under code 100.

i've also posted over community but couldn't get help there https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/367295468710196/?post_id=367295472043529

Comment: I have a similar issue but with { error_subcode: "2494010" }